# RXJS groupBy Observable <Object[]>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have `entries$: Observable<BooksOverviewGroup[]>;`:

[image]

and i would like to group them by groupId. I tried like this:

```
groupBy(books => books.map(book => book.groupId)),
 mergeMap(innerObs => innerObs.skip(1).map(books => books.map(book => book.groupTitle)));
```

However, it didn't work. How can I group by groupId in this case ? `(Observable<Object[]>)`

Comment: Do you actually want to group it into a higher order observable? Or do you actually mean to convert it into an observable of a list of groups?

Comment: I would like to group this by GroupID and get them as array back. 
Now i start with Observable<Object[]> (cause of the [] groupby didnt get me) Maybe I just need to turn this Observable<Object[]> to something like normal array and use the normal groupby. Do you know how to turn it to normal array?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Do you want a higher order observable (an observable emitting one observable per group) or a single observable that emits groups?

Comment: Sorry for that, I would like to see both variants to learn how to process the data. If it's too costly, I would like to see the solution for the higher order observable. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also confused why groupBy is giving me back an array so I can't group..

Answer (score 18):

You almost got it.

Try using `mergeMap()` or `concatMap()` before `groupBy()`.

So an example:

```
const people = [
  { name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }
];

of(people) // <- this gets Observable<Object[]>
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res), // <- use concatMap() if you care about the order
    groupBy(person => person.age, p => p.name),
    mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Output:

```
(2) [25, Array(2)]
(2) [30, Array(1)]
(2) [35, Array(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I looking for this a lot,

Comment: This is quite interesting :) Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: This answer did not help me. Actually it returns: `"TypeError: You provided 'function zipOperatorFunction(source) {"` [This was what I was looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61652403/1555615)

Answer (score 13):

## Higher-Order Observable

If you want a higher-order observable, you can actually use the `groupBy` rxjs operator.

```js
const data = [
  {groupId: "foo", value: 1},
  {groupId: "foo", value: 3},
  {groupId: "foo", value: 5},
  {groupId: "bar", value: 42},
  {groupId: "bar", value: 1337},
];

from(data).pipe(
  groupBy(item => item.groupId)
)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

This will result in an observable which emits one observable per group, and on each of those inner observables, the corresponding items will be emitted.

## Observable of Groups

If instead you want an observable which simply emits the groups, then this has actually nothing to do with rxjs or its `groupBy` operator. Instead, it's merely a basic question about how to group an array in Javascript.

There is no built-in method for this, but libraries like lodash come with such functions. You can also do it by hand:

```js
const data = [
  {groupId: "foo", value: 1},
  {groupId: "foo", value: 3},
  {groupId: "foo", value: 5},
  {groupId: "bar", value: 42},
  {groupId: "bar", value: 1337},
];

const groupBy = (data, keyFn) => data.reduce((agg, item) => {
  const group = keyFn(item);
  agg[group] = [...(agg[group] || []), item];
  return agg;
}, {});

of(data).pipe(
  map(data => groupBy(data, item => item.groupId))
)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

This will emit once for the entire data set, but will emit

```
{
  "foo":[
    {"groupId":"foo","value":1},
    {"groupId":"foo","value":3},
    {"groupId":"foo","value":5}
  ],
  "bar":[
    {"groupId":"bar","value":42},
    {"groupId":"bar","value":1337}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time. However in case of the Higher-Order Observable: 

from(data).pipe( groupBy(item => item.groupId) )

I tried this before but it didn’t work because I have an array of Observable, ist not just plain object like Object ; It’s an Object[] 

groupId is unknow in item, because item in this case is an array of object []

But if i go further :

groupBy(books => books.map(book => book.groupId))

it thinks i take array as key and turns out wrong.

I will give observable of groups a try.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `groupBy` [operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html), then merge them all.

```
$data.pipe(
    groupBy(book => book.groupId),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: it doesn't work with Observable<object[]>. I got an Array as key back.

Comment: Rxjs 6.3.2 + Angular 6.1.8 -> what @dunaskdunsay says, you you get an array back. In the code example below, typescript gives the error 'property age does not exist on type '{ name: string; age: number; }[]'
  
`const people = [{ name: 'Sue', age: 25 }, { name: 'Joe', age: 30 }, { name: 'Frank', age: 25 }, { name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }];  
const source = of(people);  
const example = source.pipe(groupBy(p => p.age));  
example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));`

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
    { groupId: "foo", value: 1 },
    { groupId: "foo", value: 3 },
    { groupId: "foo", value: 5 },
    { groupId: "bar", value: 42 },
    { groupId: "bar", value: 1337 },
];
```

```
of(data).pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res),
    groupBy(item => item.groupId),
    mergeMap(obs => {
        return obs.pipe(
            toArray(),
            map(items => {
                return { [obs.key]: items }
            })
        )
    }), toArray()
).subscribe(map((groupResponse) => {
    let groups = {};
    groupResponse.forEach((item) => { groups = { ...groups, ...item }; });
    console.log(groups);
});
```

Output will be

```
{
    "foo": [{ "groupId": "foo", "value": 3 }, { "groupId": "foo", "value": 5 }],
    "bar": [{ "groupId": "bar", "value": 42 }, { "groupId": "bar", "value": 1337 }]
}
```