# RxJS: BehaviorSubject and groupBy operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

[Here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html) it says :

```
// RxJS v6+
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { groupBy, mergeMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

const people = [
  { name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }
];
//emit each person
const source = from(people);
//group by age
const example = source.pipe(
  groupBy(person => person.age),
  // return each item in group as array
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
);
/*
  output:
  [{age: 25, name: "Sue"},{age: 25, name: "Frank"}]
  [{age: 30, name: "Joe"}]
  [{age: 35, name: "Sarah"}]
*/
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

In my code I don't create an observable with the 'from' operator, but rather with BehaviorSubject.asObservable() method.

```
Person { name: string, age: number }

    private _all: BehaviorSubject<Person[]>;
    all: Observable<Person[]>;

    constructor() {
        this._all = new BehaviorSubject<Person[]>([]);
        this.all = this._all.asObservable();
    }
```

I can iterate over 'all' with the async pipe. But when I try to use the groupBy operator I get the array itself, instead of the containing persons one by one as a stream :

```
this.all.pipe(
    groupBy(
        item => ...   <-- here 'item' is Person[], not a Person
    )
);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is (unfortunately) that it is not possible this way. Here is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332149/rxjs-groupby-observable-object) concerning a similar question.

You could do a step in between to reach the wanted goal:

**Option 1:** ***without subscription***

```
// directly access the BehaviorSubject's value
const list = from(this._all.value);
this.list.pipe(
    groupBy(
        item => ...  
    )
);
```

**Option 2:**  ***with subscription, as it is an Observable***

```
// catch the plain list inside the subscription
this.all.subscribe(result => {
    const list = from(result);
    this.list.pipe(
        groupBy(
            item => ... 
        )
    );
});
```